# Haxe Help - Manipulating Android Back Button Action

Tags: android, button, haxe, openfl, stencyl

Basically, I use Stencyl engine to make games. The engine uses Haxe and doesn't support everything that Haxe supports.

I want to manipulate he android 'back button' press. Stencyl supports code mode where I can write a haxe code. I wanted to overwrite android's default back button press. When player is playing the game, if he press back button, the game goes to background. Instead, I want the level to restart when backbutton is pressed. Can this be accomplished with any available source for Haxe?

I tried searching for any code help but can't find one. That's why messaging here. Appreciate any help.

P.S: Stencyl developer may not be a real developer for you. If that's the case, I'm not a developer. I'm just someone who uses all the resources to achieve what I want. So please avoid such topics which isn't going to help anybody.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the code. I'll try it. I have a small doubt. Where does it specify the back button? Is it the KEY_UP ?
Edit: I think I got it. It's the .ESCAPE that mentions the key we choose isn't it?

Comment: Yep, KEY_UP is the event, when key up, and ESCAPE is code of the back button on Android

Comment: Thanks soooo much for helping. I have some difficulty making it work but I will try to fix it myself for few more hours before bringing it here.

Comment: Also, there are two other buttons in android phone. I think they are named 'Home' and 'Menu'. Can these also be used in similar ways? 

That is, just replacing 'HOME' or 'MENU' at 'ESCAPE' in the above code will work? I could've tested it myself but since I can't test this code yet, I'm asking you the question. 

Once again thank you so much for your help. This brings lot more possibilities for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below code

```
Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(openfl.events.KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeypress);

...

private function checkKeypress(e:openfl.events.KeyboardEvent):Void
{
    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
        case openfl.ui.Keyboard.ESCAPE:
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            restartLevel();
    }
}
private function restartLevel():Void
{
    //your code to restart level here
}
```

Comment: I believe this should work, provided Stencly is using a recent version of lime. This behavior is analagous to Alt+Enter causing a fullscreen action on Windows, and a while back I talked to Joshua about making sure that behavior was suppress-able, and this was exactly the prescribed method he suggested.

Comment: Thanks soooo much for helping. I have some difficulty making it work but I will try to fix it myself for few more hours before bringing it here.

 Also, there are two other buttons in android phone. I think they are named 'Home' and 'Menu'. Can these also be used in similar ways? That is, just replacing 'HOME' or 'MENU' at 'ESCAPE' in the above code will work? I could've tested it myself but since I can't test this code yet, I'm asking you the question. Once again thank you so much for your help. This brings lot more possibilities for me.

Comment: Hi again, 

I'm receiving 'characters 0-7 : Unexpected private' error. I added this code inside when updating event. Thus, whenever player press the back button it will be recognized. 

Am I missing something?

Comment: I was wondering whether the error is with the '...' as it serves no purpose I assume? I'll also post the whole code shortly

Comment: You don't need to add this in each update. Add Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(openfl.events.KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeypress); somewhere in initialization, and functions near others. As i remember you can't redefine HOME button

Comment: I search a little, if you use something like http://www.stencyl.com/help/view/code-mode/ for code writing, you should write Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(openfl.events.KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeypress); inside init function. As I understand Stencyl use "public inline" functions for some reason, so you should try replace "private" with "public inline" in my code above

Comment: You seem to be of great help. Since I'm not a coder but learning to be, this helps a lot.

I'll test this and update if it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: It throws an error 'Unknown Identifier: Lib'

I wrote like this in code mode:
code
 override public function init()
 {
  Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(openfl.events.KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeypress);
 }

public inline function checkKeypress(e:openfl.events.KeyboardEvent):Void
{
    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
        case openfl.ui.Keyboard.ESCAPE:
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            restartLevel();
    }
}
public inline function restartLevel():Void
{
    //your code to restart level here
    reloadCurrentScene(null, createCrossfadeTransition(0));
}

Comment: Sorry. I can't enter the code properly. I had a discussion in Stencyl forum who says that I must import lib but they don't remember the package name. I don't know the package name. I tried to find in Google but can't get relevant results. Any help?